PyTorch Distributed and Multiprocessing: Processes execute from the start of the whole script not the place where them are created
Introduction
I'm new in PyTorch distributed and multiprocessing and I met the unexpected problems:

I have leant that processes created by spawn will execute the given function, but my processes execute the whole script.
A part of processes print the result, and the cmd frozed.

Details
There is a detailed description:
My test script:
import os
import torch
import torch.cuda as cuda
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
import torch.distributed as dist


def print_tensors(rank, size, world_size):
    cuda.set_device(rank)
    dist.init_process_group(backend='nccl', init_method='env://', world_size=world_size)
    print(f'{rank} -> {torch.randn(size)}')               # <----- output_1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    world_size = int(os.environ['WORLD_SIZE'])
    ngpus = cuda.device_count()
    print(f'ngpus = {ngpus} world_size = {world_size}')    # <---- output_0
    mp.spawn(print_tensors, args=(2, world_size), nprocs=world_size)

I use torchrun to launch the multiprocess task:
torchrun \
    --nnodes=1 \
    --nproc_per_node=4 \
    test.py \

I run my codes on 1 node with 4 gpus, the outputs are:
ngpus = 4 world_size = 4
ngpus = 4 world_size = 4
ngpus = 4 world_size = 4
2 -> tensor([ 0.2236, -0.1315])
0 -> tensor([-0.5984,  0.7586])
...

where ... in the above bash means that the program is frozen without any other outputs.
Questions
So my questions are:

Why the processes created from spawn will execute the codes (tag output_0 in code) that not included in function print_tensor?
Why the program frozed after part of outputs.

Environment

Unbuntu 20.04
Python 3.10
PyTorch 1.12
GPU 3090x4
Number of Node 1

Thanks!!!
I have tried to use just one GPU to run, it outputs the expected results and ends correctly.

Sorry... the word them in the title should be they...

You could try printing __name__ from each process to see what internal names the processes got during creation. Anything appearing as __main__ will print the ngps-line. There should be only one.
